# Support with 'Quick Sort' Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I am having problems with my **quick-sort algorithm implementation** that uses **recursion**. When I use the function on an array with **duplicate numbers**, it **ignores those numbers** in the final result and I don't know why. Anyone know what I did wrong?
(JavaScript)

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

let quickSort = (arr) => {
    if (arr.length <= 1) return arr;
    
    const pivot = arr[getRandomInt(arr.length)]
    let smallerArr = [];
    let greaterArr = [];
    
    for (let item of arr) {
        if (item !== pivot) {
            if (item > pivot) {
                greaterArr.push(item);
                continue
            }
            smallerArr.push(item);
        }
        
    }
    let sorted = quickSort(smallerArr);
    sorted = sorted.concat([pivot],quickSort(greaterArr));
    console.log(sorted);
    return sorted;
}
quickSort([5,7,6,23,6]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You only want to skip the element whose `pivotIndex` matches with the current `index`. I switched back to the `for(let i = 0,index......)` approach to keep track of the same. What you're currently doing is skipping all the **items** whose value matches with the `pivot` which means **duplicates** are also removed from being considered if the `pivot` element has **duplicates** in the array.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

let quickSort = (arr) => {
    if (arr.length <= 1) return arr;
    
    const pivotIndex = getRandomInt(arr.length);
    const pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
    let smallerArr = [];
    let greaterArr = [];
    for(let index = 0;index<arr.length;index++)
    {
            if(index===pivotIndex)
               continue;
            const item = arr[index];   
            if (item > pivot) 
            greaterArr.push(item);
            else 
            smallerArr.push(item);
    }
    let sorted = quickSort(smallerArr);
    sorted = sorted.concat(pivot,quickSort(greaterArr));
    console.log(sorted);
    return sorted;
}
quickSort([5,7,6,23,6,6,6,6]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I must have overlooked that bug. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `item !== pivot` is false? You seem to skip that item.

Comment: See the response to the person above ^

Answer (score 0):

You need to make clear what your code should do when item === pivot.
Right now your code is only ignoring those values because it is not inserting on either greaterArr and smallerArr.
Add an else statement to fix this.